# Uncaught Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception: The mysql driver is not currently installed

Tags: php, redhat, rhel6

I have RHEL 6.8 and I am installing `PHP 7.1.3` from a repository `remi-php71`. I have installed PHP, but I also needed some extra modules, one of these is `php_mysql`. The repository `remi-php71` provided a package: `php-mysqlnd`. But no `php_mysql`. [Reading](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqlnd.php) about `mysqlnd`, I found it right to install `php_mysqlnd`, instead of 'php_mysql' (which was anyway not available in the repo).

But in spite of having `php_mysqlnd` installed. I get these apache logs:  "Uncaught Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception: The mysql driver is not currently installed in /usr/share/php/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:112.....".

The list of PHP packages I have installed:

1. php-cli-7.1.3-1.el6.remi.x86_64
2. php-process-7.1.3-1.el6.remi.x86_64
3. php-mcrypt-7.1.3-1.el6.remi.x86_64
4. php-ZendFramework-Db-Adapter-Pdo-Mysql-1.12.20-1.el6.remi.noarch
5. php-common-7.1.3-1.el6.remi.x86_64
6. php-7.1.3-1.el6.remi.x86_64
7. php-pdo-7.1.3-1.el6.remi.x86_64
8. php-xml-7.1.3-1.el6.remi.x86_64
9. php-bcmath-7.1.3-1.el6.remi.x86_64
10. php-ZendFramework-1.12.20-1.el6.remi.noarch
11. php-ZendFramework-Db-Adapter-Pdo-1.12.20-1.el6.remi.noarch
12. php-json-7.1.3-1.el6.remi.x86_64
13. php-opcache-7.1.3-1.el6.remi.x86_64
14. php-pear-1.10.3-1.el6.remi.noarch
15. php-mysqlnd-7.1.3-1.el6.remi.x86_64

Can you please point in the right direction? I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115657/mysql-driver-not-installed-error-for-zend-application), couldn't find it useful in my case.

Answer (score 2):

1/ [mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) extension is deprecated for years and removed from PHP 7

2/ the **php-mysqlnd** package provides 3 extensions

- the [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extension
- the [pdo_mysql](http://php.net/pdo_mysql) PDO driver
- the [mysqlnd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) driver (not a real extension, used by above)

Is seems you are still using ZF1, which is terrible old, and very probably not compatible with recent PHP versions. For new development, you should really consider using ZF 2 or ZF 3.

From above error message, you probably need **pdo_mysql**, so **php-mysqlnd** should be enough.

As a workaround you can use [php-pecl-mysql](https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/php71/x86_64/repoview/php-pecl-mysql.html) which provides the old extension (but this is really a **workaround**, this extension is only provided for **legacy** app, and will probably be never released as "stable")

Comment: Also remember to always restart apache or php-fpm after having installed a new extension.

Comment: I am sorry I don't know why I didn't followUp with your answer... Sorry can't tell whether this had fixed my issue or not...